# Chrome 41 Parsing JSON Object Token Error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, browser, dojo

We have a corporate-wide web app. It runs on Dojo version 1.12.2. It runs fine without problem on Chrome and Firefox, but on Chrome 41, it fails to load a certain Dojo module with the following message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

It turns out this following line was broken:

```
myTool = new MyTool({toolConfig});
```

where `toolConfig` is a simple Json object.

Now I replace the offending line with the following, and Chrome 41 and others browsers work as expected:

```
var aConfig = {};
aConfig["toolConfig"] = toolConfig;
myool = new MyTool(aConfig);
```

It appears that Chrome 41 fails to parse the offending line. Is it because the line is of new JS standards (I am not an expert front-end developer)? Or is it a known bug in Chrome 41? I did a quick research but couldn't find anything.

Comment: does `{ "toolConfig": toolConfig }` work?

Comment: Haven't tried it, will try again tomorrow at work.

Comment: If you literally used `{toolConfig}`, you are using ES2015 [shorthand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)